# Recreate elasticsearch filtered query using Elasticsearch.NET

Tags: c#, .net, nest, elasticsearch

I'm having trouble getting the correct elasticsearch query string to be output from Elasticsearch.NET api.  This is the query I want to be generated:

```
{
   "size": 5000,
   "sort": [
      {
         "id": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "match_all": {}
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "stateType": {
                           "value": 2
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "or": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "concealed": true
                  }
               },
               {
                  "term": {
                     "govt": true
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The C# code I used to get that is as follows:

```cs
FilterContainer filterContainer = new FilterContainer();

filterContainer &= Filter<ElasticsearchLoad>.Or(f => f.Term("concealed", true));
filterContainer &= Filter<ElasticsearchLoad>.Or(f => f.Term("govt", true));

QueryContainer container = new MatchAllQuery();
container &= Query<ElasticsearchLoad>.Filtered(fq => Query<ElasticsearchLoad>.Term(l => l.StateType, 2));

SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchLoad> searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchLoad>();
searchDescriptor.Query(container).Filter(filterContainer);
searchDescriptor.Size(5000);

var searchResponse = Client.Search<ElasticsearchMyDoc>(s => searchDescriptor);
```

As you can see, I'm not getting the "query" : { "filtered" : { ...}} syntax to be generated, and, for the life of me, I can't figure out how.  Could someone please help me to determine the C# syntax needed to get this to work??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is how to construct a filtered query using Nest. See my solution below. In addition to that, I would suggest you use `boolean` filters (like I've done below) instead of `and`/`or` filters as the former are usually cached and hence execute very fast. Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets).

```
FilterContainer filterContainer = null;

filterContainer |= Filter<ElasticsearchMyDoc>.Term("concealed", true);
filterContainer |= Filter<ElasticsearchMyDoc>.Term("govt", true);

QueryContainer queryContainer = new MatchAllQuery();
queryContainer &= Query<ElasticsearchMyDoc>.Term(l => l.StateType, 2);

SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchMyDoc> searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchMyDoc>();
searchDescriptor.Query(qd => qd.Filtered(fq =>
    {
        fq.Filter(f => filterContainer);
        fq.Query(q => queryContainer);
    }));

searchDescriptor.Size(5000);
var searchResponse = Client.Search<ElasticsearchMyDoc>(s => searchDescriptor);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!  And thanks for helping me to understand the Elasticsearch.NET API better!

Answer (score 3):

Hope you don't mind I've used fluent syntax.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Size(5000)
    .Sort(x => x.OnField(f => f.Id).Descending())
    .Query(query => query
        .Filtered(filtered => filtered
            .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(
                m => m.MatchAll(),
                m => m.Term(t => t.OnField(f => f.StateType).Value("2")))))
            .Filter(filter => filter.Or(
                f => f.Term(t => t.Concealed, true),
                f => f.Term(t => t.Govt, true))))));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Rob, Wow, thank you!  I've plugged that in and it works perfectly!  The problem is that it is using the fluent syntax, and I am in need of it to use the query container, et al... since the query is built by user input.  Is this possible to do using the OIS syntax.  If so, could you help?  I'm new to this, and it's obviously not clicking for me :-/